# Supercollider no longer works on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian-buster, jack, supercollider

I have been using a number of Raspberry Pi 4 devices running Raspbian Buster with the standard packaged version of Supercollider (3.10.0) sound synth for some time. Last week, an 'apt update & upgrade' stopped them all from working. This only affected the Raspberry Pi OS as the other versions on ubuntu (amd/intel) all continued to function. Installing ubuntu on the RPi4 was partially successful, but the sound output was badly distorted.

I could not find out whether it was a problem with Supercollider, Jackd or an updated OS file that either one of Supercollider or Jackd rely on. I tried a weeks' worth of fixes and solutions found elsewhere on the interweb, none worked, although error messages were similar.

I have finally got myself back to square one by reimaging with 2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-full.img and NOT updating anything with 'apt update/upgrade'.

If anyone is interested in this issue being resolved and are able to provide me some useful tips on upgrading a bit at a time or comparing the files in two debian images, please let me know. Otherwise I will just continue with this old OS version and hope someone else fixes this issue before I have to apt update. Anyone else with this issue, I hope that knowing that 2020-08-20-raspios-buster is a potential solution will be of use to you.

I have tried so, so many different solutions and absolutely nothing worked, so no more suggestions like that please.

Here are the consistent error messages for users seraching:-

```
JackPosixProcessSync::LockedTimedWait error usec = 5000000 err = Connection timed out
Driver is not running
Cannot read socket fd = 5 err = Success
Cannot create new client
CheckRes error
JackSocketClientChannel read fail
Cannot open SuperCollider client
JackShmReadWritePtr1::~JackShmReadWritePtr1 - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
terminate called without an active exception
could not initialize audio.
ALSA: poll time out, polled for 34828070 usecs
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, stopping...
```

Comment: This looks like a jack problem.  Are you able to start jack?

Comment: I believe that I can start Jackd, but I have no idea whether it is working. As soon as SClang is started I get the same errors as if I started Supercollider without starting jackd first.

Comment: Audacity can use either pulse or jack. Can you test if it works with jack? Also, check the graph window in qjacktl. Does it show the system input and output? When you start the sc server, does it also show up? Can these things be connected?